# How do I use Ajax to call a backend function in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

For example, I have a "Delete" link on a page defined like this

```
<a onclick="deleteArticle()" href="#">Delete</a>
```

and the js script

```
<script>
    function deleteArticle() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this item?")) {
            // call the backend function
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the link is clicked, the confirmation box pops up and if clicked yes, I want the browser to send Ajax request to call a backend function called deleteArticle(article).

I already get the backend stuff done but I'm new to Ajax and don't know how to make it work in the frontend, please help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess when you said to call spring mvc function, you mean to call a controller on spring side. If that is the case, you can use Jquery ajax to send a get or post request to the controller. You need to know the url mapped to the function that want to be called, so that you can make ajax request that. Check Jquery Ajax and it is really straight forward.